# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {46521B1F-0A5B-4871-A4C2-FD5C9276F4C6} failed due to the following error: 80040154

Tags: .net, iis

I'm using Some Dll's which are developed in 32 bit application.
when I'm trying to use the some Dll's  in 64 bit operating system I'm getting the following error.

"Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {46521B1F-0A5B-4871-A4C2-FD5C9276F4C6} failed due to the following error: 80040154."

When i use the same Dll's in Windows Forms it works fine. but when i place in IIS I'm getting the above error.

I tried all possibilites like "Enable 32 bit applications", "Change Platform to X86","register the dll's in SysWOW64 using regsvr32","provide everyone permissions to that Dll's".....

Can any one suggest , it helps a lot to me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

80040154 is "Class is not Registered"
Your 64-bit IIS can't call a 32-bit COM Dll.  You are getting the message because the IIS is looking in the native 64-bit registry and you've registered the Dll in the 32-bit registry view because it's a 32-bit Dll.

Try configuring IIS to run 32-bit Web applications on 64-bit Windows. [For example.](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/13f991a5-45eb-496c-8618-2179c3753bb0.mspx?mfr=true)